# instead of PIMPL, use the implstore

Tags: c++, c++11

If you can't afford the extra level of indirection, that comes with PIMPL, use the `implstore`! Improvements?

```
#ifndef IMPLSTORE_HPP
# define IMPLSTORE_HPP
# pragma once

#include <cstddef>

#include <new>

#include <type_traits>

#include <utility>

template <class U, ::std::size_t N = 64>
class implstore
{
public:
  implstore()
  {
    static_assert(sizeof(U) <= sizeof(store_),
      "impl too large");
    static_assert(::std::is_default_constructible<U>{},
      "impl is not default constructible");
    new (store_) U;

    deleter_ = deleter_stub;
  }

  template <typename ...A>
  explicit implstore(A&& ...args)
  {
    static_assert(sizeof(U) <= sizeof(store_),
      "impl too large");
    new (store_) U(::std::forward<A>(args)...);

    deleter_ = deleter_stub;
  }

  ~implstore() { *this && (deleter_(*this), true); }

  template <::std::size_t M>
  implstore(implstore<U, M> const& other)
  {
    static_assert(::std::is_copy_constructible<U>{},
      "impl is not copy constructible");
    new (store_) U(*other);

    deleter_ = other.deleter_;
  }

  template <::std::size_t M>
  implstore(implstore<U, M>&& other)
  {
    static_assert(::std::is_move_constructible<U>{},
      "impl is not move constructible");

    new (store_) U(*other);

    deleter_ = other.deleter_;
  }

  template <::std::size_t M>
  implstore& operator=(implstore<U, M> const& other)
  {
    static_assert(::std::is_copy_assignable<U>{},
      "impl is not copy assignable");

    **this = *other;

    deleter_ = other.deleter_;

    return *this;
  }

  template <::std::size_t M>
  implstore& operator=(implstore<U, M>&& other)
  {
    static_assert(::std::is_move_assignable<U>{},
      "impl is not move assignable");

    **this = ::std::move(*other);

    deleter_ = other.deleter_;

    return *this;
  }

  U const* operator->() const noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  U* operator->() noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  U const* get() const noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  U* get() noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  U const& operator*() const noexcept
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  U& operator*() noexcept
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return deleter_; }

private:
  static void deleter_stub(implstore& is)
  {
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[sizeof(U) ? 1 : -1];
    (void)sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    is->~U();
  }

private:
  void (*deleter_)(implstore&){};

  alignas(::std::max_align_t) char store_[N];
};

#endif // IMPLSTORE_HPP
```

Edit. Here is the version built around Dyps' suggestions. From what I understood, Dyp suggests the `implstore` class to inherit the type traits of the `Impl` class it wraps, as much as possible. In order for this thing to work you need to declare and define (in the containing class) your own destructor,  whatever copy constructors you might need and whatever assignment operators you might need.

```
#ifndef IMPLSTORE_HPP
# define IMPLSTORE_HPP
# pragma once

#include <cstddef>

#include <new>

#include <type_traits>

#include <utility>

template <class U, ::std::size_t N = 64>
class implstore
{
public:
  static constexpr ::std::size_t const buffer_size = N;

  using value_type = U;

  template <typename ...A, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_constructible<U, A...>{}>::type>
  implstore(A&& ...args)
  {
    static_assert(sizeof(U) <= sizeof(store_),
      "impl too large");
    new (static_cast<void*>(&store_)) U(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  ~implstore() { get()->~U(); }

  implstore(implstore const& other)
  {
    new (static_cast<void*>(&store_)) U(*other);
  }

  template <::std::size_t M, typename K = U, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_copy_constructible<K>{}>::type>
  implstore(implstore<U, M> const& other)
  {
    new (static_cast<void*>(&store_)) U(*other);
  }

  template <::std::size_t M, typename K = U, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_move_constructible<K>{}>::type>
  implstore(implstore<U, M>&& other)
  {
    new (static_cast<void*>(&store_)) U(::std::move(*other));
  }

  implstore& operator=(implstore const& other)
  {
    **this = *other;

    return *this;
  }

  template <::std::size_t M, typename K = U, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_copy_assignable<K>{}>::type>
  implstore& operator=(implstore<U, M> const& other)
  {
    **this = *other;

    return *this;
  }

  template <::std::size_t M, typename K = U, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_move_assignable<K>{}>::type>
  implstore& operator=(implstore<U, M>&& other)
  {
    **this = ::std::move(*other);

    return *this;
  }

  U const* operator->() const noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U const*>(&store_);
  }

  U* operator->() noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(&store_);
  }

  U const* get() const noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U const*>(&store_);
  }

  U* get() noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<U*>(&store_);
  }

  U const& operator*() const noexcept
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<U const*>(&store_);
  }

  U& operator*() noexcept
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<U*>(&store_);
  }

private:
  typename ::std::aligned_storage<N>::type store_;
};

#endif // IMPLSTORE_HPP
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what you're trying to do...

Comment: I think you could reduce the alignment requirements to the max requirements for a type of the max size. This is what [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) does per default.

Comment: Why did you use this: `*this && (deleter_(*this), true)` Is there any particular reason not to write `if(*this) deleter_(*this)`?

Comment: Are you using the `deleter_` to make sure `U` is complete when calling its dtor?

Comment: @dyp I think `new` cannot operate on incomplete types, as for deleter_, no, I was merely trying to make sure, the destructor of object contained in the store_ was called. As for alignment requirements, please write an answer/fix, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @dyp as for the cryptic `deleter_` invocation, I simply like one-liners like that.

Comment: Well both `new` and the destructor call `is->~U();` require a complete type. I just think that if you can avoid the `deleter_`, you save 8 bytes, and that can be quite a large fraction of the total size of the object. However, you might get UB if you avoid `deleter_` and the user is not careful to define its ctor (of the class using `implstore`) out-of-line.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks, dyp, good advice, and I suppose you meant that I should use `std::aligned_storage` with the default `Align` parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure any more if it's UB or just ill-formed with a compiler diagnostic required :/ I'll try to figure that out. -- and yes, I suggested using `std::aligned_storage`, but I'm not sure whether that or the `char` array you used can be aliased will well-formed behaviour for all your member functions. I find the description of aliasing a bit tricky. (Edit: I think it's just ill-formed, `delete` has UB if its an incomplete type, but you don't use `delete`)

Comment: IIRC constructor templates are never considered to be copy/move constructors. You do have a custom destructor, so there will be no compiler-generated move constructor, but there might be a compiler-generated copy constructor. Similarly for assignment-operators.

Comment: @dyp I can't make this work without `deleter_`, your more than welcome to write an answer. The problem is, that apparently one cannot call the destructor of an instance of an incomplete type.

Comment: @user1095108 Sure, you have to define the destructor of the class which uses `deleter_` out-of-line, i.e. at a point where the `U` of `implstore` is complete. Maybe there's a solution which allows both (efficient storage and usage of a deleter), e.g. as specializations.

Comment: I think btw that `static_assert`ing for the size is a great idea. It doesn't free the user from providing a size in the header file, but at least it produces a compile-time error if the buffer is too small. OTOH, a warning would be nice if the size is too big - I understand that shouldn't be an error since you might want to change the stored type at some time without changing the size argument of `implstore`, but users might inadvertently waste space.

Comment: Take a look at [this test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/827541a21554e74b). As I said: **You need to have a non-template copy ctor, copy assignment-op and their move counterparts, since function templates are never considered as copy/move ctors or copy/move assignment-ops.** The compiler will generate default versions, which will memcpy the byte array.

Comment: (Actually, you only need the copy versions, since the move versions won't be generated due to the user-defined destructor.)

Comment: @dyp I believe, that without a non-default copy/move constructor (in `wrap`), chances are that the default copying constructor wouldn't work anyway, because `U` is not necessarily complete. Perhaps the safest thing would be to delete both the non-templated copy constructor and the non-templated assignment operator.

Comment: Of course they won't work when declared&defined by the compiler or otherwise defined in the body of the `wrap` (where `U` might not be complete). But "deleting" the non-template copy/move functions makes the `implstore` noncopyable/nonmovable, so you'd have to provide alternatives, e.g. via a tag type (deleting = *if someone attempts to call it => compile-time error*). I think that's much more inconvenient since the user who writes `wrap` then has to explicitly call the copy/move ctors for *all* members, and similarly has to implement assignment operators.

Comment: @dyp I delete the `implstore`'s nontemplated copy constructor and assignment operator. `wrap` can provide its own, calling the templated versions. That was the idea. I've updated the code.

Comment: You should make a small test case and really test your code every time you change it. As I said: **deleting a function doesn't make it go away, it makes calling this function illegal**. And since you still have overload resolution between e.g. the deleted copy-ctor and the ctor template, the copy ctor might still be selected. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e1d0b82047965a4) -- By the way, a default constructor of `wrap` has the same problem with in-class-body definitions.

Comment: If you'd like to continue this discussion, please take it to chat.  Thanks.

Comment: [related](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm).

Comment: @JerryCoffin From ages ago, before `c++11`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new (store_) U;
```

You should explicitly cast to a `void*` to avoid calling any user-defined allocation functions instead of placement-new.

```
void (*deleter_)(implstore&){};
```

To my eyes, this is quite ugly. It almost looks like a member function, but it's a pointer. I'd prefer

```
using deleter_t = void(*)(implstore&);
deleter_t deleter_ = nullptr;
```

But I think both the NSDMI (`= nullptr` or `{}`) and `deleter_` itself is unnecessary. Since you now changed the code so that every constructor initializes the stored object, you don't even need it as a check whether or not the object is initialized. If you leave out the `deleter_`, you force the user of `implstore` to define their dtor out-of-line at a point where the type stored inside the `implstore` is complete. If the user doesn't do that, the error message is not very nice (destructor of incomplete type called at the point where the class using `implstore` is destroyed), but it saves you 8 bytes per object. The cost of the function call has to be paid anyway AFAIK.

```
template <typename ...A>
explicit implstore(A&& ...args)
```

Typically, such constructors are too greedy and should be restricted by SFINAE via `std::is_constructible` so that they only produce instantiations for arguments for which the stored object can be constructed. Otherwise, `implstore` will appear constructible from *any* argument set (`std::is_constructible<implstore, ..>` will always yield `true`).

Additionally, constructor templates and assignment-operator templates do not suppress the generation of compiler-generated copy/move constructors and assignment-operators.

---

```
~implstore() { *this && (deleter_(*this), true); }
```

I'd prefer

```
~implstore() { if(*this) deleter_(*this); }
```

which is shorter and (arguably) clearer. But neither is necessary with your changed code:

```
~implstore() { get()->~U(); }
```

should be sufficient.

Here's an example of how it can/needs to be used:

```
// MyClass.hpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    struct Impl;
    implstore<Impl, 10> impl;
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(MyClass const&);
    ~MyClass();
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const&);

    void meow();
};


// MyClass.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.hpp"

struct MyClass::Impl
{
    void meow() { std::cout << "meow!\n"; }
};

MyClass::MyClass() = default;
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass const&) = default;
MyClass::~MyClass() = default;
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass const&) = default;

void MyClass::meow() { impl.get()->meow(); }


// other.cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"

int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    m.meow();
}
```

The important part of course is the out-of-line definition of *all* member functions of `MyClass` that require `Impl` to be complete. This includes the destructor.

---

```
template <::std::size_t M>
implstore(implstore<U, M> const& other)
```

.. and other constructors: I'd use constructor delegation or an initialization function to get rid of the duplicated code. Similarly,

```
U const* operator->() const noexcept
{
  return reinterpret_cast<U*>(store_);
}
```

and all other variations can use a single (private const) member function instead of repeating that cast.

```
alignas(::std::max_align_t) char store_[N];
```

Can, I think, be reduced to

```
typename std::aligned_storage<N>::type store_;
```

But I'm not sure about the aliasing correctness in either case (especially combined with the `reinterpret_cast`s). But that's probably a StackOverflow question.

---

Furthermore, I miss the publication of the template arguments. As a user, you can always get them out of the type by partial specialization, so they're not private anyway.

```
using value_type = U;
static constexpr ::std::size_t buffer_size = N;
```

And you could use those names instead of template parameters inside the class itself (arguably "nicer" and decouples the types from the template parameters).

Comment: Not sure what to think about `::std`. Not sure how to search for previous discussion on this topic, either :/

Comment: If this worked `~implstore() { get()->~U(); }` it would be great, but compiler complains about an incomplete type. I need to support incomplete types, so the `deleter_` indirection appears to be necessary for a successful compile.

Comment: @user1095108 I've added an example that compiles with clang++3.3